# Calculate the probability, that a man repair 20 machines in 8 hours. It is correct my work?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

The problem statement said:

> The servicing of a machine requires two separate steps, with the time
>   needed for the 1st step being an exponential random variable with mean
>   10 minutes and the time for the second step being an independent
>   exponential random variable with mean 15 minutes. If a repairperson
>   has 20 machines to service, compute the aproximate the probability
>   that all the work can be completed in 8 hours.

My work:

*) Let Xi be the time to service the ith machine, then

```
 E[Xi]=E[X1]+E[X2]=10+15=25min (Thanks Andre!)

 V[Xi]=V[X1]+V[X2]=100+225=325
```

**) Therefore, Xi is modeled by a normal r.v. with parameters

```
 E[X]=20*E[Xi]=500
 V[X]=20*V[Xi]=6500  then std=80.622
```

***) Last Part

Now, I know that X is the sum of 20 independent and identict distributives r.v. x1, x2 ….x20 where each xi is the time for the repair of the ith machine.

P(X<8*60min)=P(z<(480-500)/80.622)=P(z<-0.248071)=  2.74855E-10

**Question:
Is may procedure correct? Looks very small probability, it is right?**
Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Note that $10+15=25$, not $35$.

Comment: Thanks, I fix my mistake but I'm still concern about that the probability is pretty low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks right, except for the last value. You made a mistake using your calculator or reading values from the table. 
I got
$$
P\left(Z<\frac{480-500}{\sqrt{6500}}\right) = P(Z<-0.2480695) = 0.4020403$$
Notice that this value is "close" to $50\%$. That makes sense since the standardized value is very small (-0.248), close to the mean.

Comment: Thanks! Yes know the probability looks logicaly correct :-)